# How to provide password for Capistrano rails 3.1 app deployment to aws ec2 ubuntu server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, capistrano

We are trying to deploy a rails 3.1 app on a aws ec2 instance running ubuntu 12.04. With cap deploy, However, we are stuck with the password hint. There is only private key in aws ecs login and there is no password. How can we pass the ssh login for ec2 deployment?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to solve this scenario:

1. On the local machine, generate a key using e.g. ssh-keygen. Keep the standard location to not overcomplicate things, i.e. keyfiles should be ~/.ssh/id_rsa and id_rsa.pub; SKIP THIS STEP IF YOU ALREADY HAVE KEYS IN .ssh
2. Copy the content of the id_rsa.pub file
3. SSH into the EC2 instance using your .pem keyfile
4. Paste the content of your local id_rsa.pub into /home/[YOUR_EC2_USER]/.ssh/authorized_keys

You should now be able to use capistrano for your deployment.

Comment: Worked for me, all the other workaround for using .pem file was a waste of time. This solution is quick and simple. Thanks!!!

Comment: 1.It's not localmachine ,in fact ,it's ec2 machine.  Use this command get public key.ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "root@localhost"